# Is the speed of multiplying/adding interger a constant, regardless of how big the number is?

Tags: math, integer, cpu

Is `3*3` faster, or takes the same number CPU cycles as `1000*1000` (values are C `int`). Is this claim applied to all other arithmetic operators, including floating point ones?

Comment: When you say "values are int", what language did you have in mind? `int` in Java and `int` in Python are very different beasts, for example.

Comment: The arithmetics operations have a *bit complexity*, i.e. the amount of "steps" performed given the number of bits. None are O(1), meaning, none take the same amount of steps irrespective of the number of bits. The greater the number of bits the lengthier the operation. You can find the exact complexity with a simple Google search.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I mean C `int`, or machine `int`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom That term is new to me. I searched and found nothing clear to me. While I do understand that the greater number of bits makes the operation lengthier, I want to ask that when the number of bit is the same (e.g. `int * int` in C), then does the value of the operand affect the time for the operation (3 is much smaller than 1000, so it *should* take less time to do 3*3 than 1000*1000, although both is represented in 32-bit format)?

Comment: @MinhNghĩa Oh, ok, I misunderstood you. Generally speaking, yes, the time depends on the actual values, but not trivially. As an answer pointed out, the basic operations are performed in hardware and hardware typically works with fixed timings. But optimizations are possible (e.g. detection and skipping of non-relevant bits) and when it comes to floating-points, some operations may be microcoded and in such cases they are terminated as soon as the result is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPUs typically implement multiplication for fixed sized numbers in hardware, and no matter which two numbers you pass in, the circuitry is going to run through all the bits even if most of them are zeros. For examples of how you can multiply two numbers in hardware see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier

This means the time it takes to multiply two "int"s in C is pretty much a constant.

Caveat: You may find that multiplication by a power of 2 is much faster than multiplication in general. The compiler is free to not use the multiply instruction and replace it with bit shifts and adds if it produces the correct result.